# How to switch from Ubuntu 18.04 to kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux, ubuntu

I am using now ubuntu 18.04.1 and i wanna make dual boot with kali linux. How to do that?

Comment: Nothing in this question is about information security, i.e. the question is off-topic. It basically asks how to install another Linux distribution in parallel to an existing one.

Comment: Yep that is so but where need i question this when not in forum where all user are using kali linux

Comment: Not everybody is using Kali Linux here. Not everybody using Kali Linux is on this site. Not every question which could be answered be somebody here is automatically on-topic. Try superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this countless times, when I used to experiment with Linux a lot.

First things first, you need to allocate space for your Kali Linux installation, I recommend a minimum of 50gb. You can do this using a partition editor, like [GParted](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd).

Now, you should have some un-allocated space, which is where we will stick the Kali installation.

Burn the [Kali Linux ISO](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) to a USB, using a tool suck as `dd`, or `Rufus` (instructions to do so [here](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install)).

Now, we will boot from the USB. Each computer is different, you will need to search that one up.

When the Kali Linux boot menu is show, choose `Graphical install`, by using the arrow keys and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Proceed to choose your language, location, etc etc, until you get to the partitioning screen. From there, select `Manual`.

You will see your partitions, select the un-allocated (`FREE SPACE`) space that you setup previously, then choose `Create a new partition`, then choose how much space you want for the installation (the maximum amount should already be filled out).

Make sure that `Use as:` is set to `EXT4`, as this is the most used filesystem.
`Mount point` should be `/`, `Mount options`: `default`, and set the `Label` to anything you want, for example: `Kali Linux`.

Then set the `Bootable flag` to `On`, so that you can boot from the Kali machine. You can set it to off, but you will need to upgrade the `GRUB2` in Ubuntu for Kali to show up.

Then choose `Done`, `Finish`, and here is a really important step: It should say something like `If you continue, the changes written below will be written to the disks`. MAKE SURE that only one change is there, it should say something like: `partition #(partition number) of SCSI... as EXT4`.

If it has only one entry, choose `Yes`, then wait for it to install the system.

The next input, should be `Configure the package manager`, and it will ask if you want to use a network mirror, select `No`, then `Yes` on the GRUB bootloader installation screen (that is, if you selected yes to make the partition bootable), then select `/dev/sda`, or whatever hard-drive you are using.

Then, you are done, wait for it to say `Installation complete`.